# CoreData - insertNewObjectForEntityForName can't set attribute

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, runtime-error

I'm using CoreData with one entity and two attributes for that entity.
Entity: Binder
Attributes: Name, lastOpened
,br>
I'm able to insert a new object of the entity with no problem, and I can also set it's name, but I can not set it's lastOpened attribute.
Here is my code:

```
Binder *newBinder = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Binder" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[newBinder setName:@"Binder"];
[newBinder setLastOpened:[NSDate date]]; //Tried this first
newBinder.lastOpened = [NSDate date]; //No compiler warning either
```

However, when I run the app, I get an error of `-[Binder setLastOpened:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9688870`
I can verify that the memory address shown is actually the correct Binder object. Any idea as to why I can set one attribute but not another one? Thanks.
Binder.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Cards;

@interface Binder : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * lastOpened;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *cards;
@end

@interface Binder (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addCardsObject:(Cards *)value;
- (void)removeCardsObject:(Cards *)value;
- (void)addCards:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeCards:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Binder.m:

```
#import "Binder.h"
#import "Cards.h"


@implementation Binder

@dynamic name;
@dynamic lastOpened;
@dynamic cards;

@end
```

Comment: Seems that your model doesn't' have such attribute 'lastOpened'. Print your managed object model and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode occasionally goofs up rebuilding changes to xcdatamodel. Next time, try doing a clean build.

Also, you should not hard core the class-name string because it will break refactor.

```
[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Binder class]) inManagedObjectContext:context]
```

Also, add a prefix to class names and managed objects. (e.g. prefer XYZBinder to just Binder). You will avoid future grief of namespace collisions.

Comment: Thanks of this answer Lorean, it really helped me out. However, every time I rebuild the app I now need to do a Clean and Clean Build. Any idea how I could make a permanent fix for that?

Answer (score 0):

You may have already loaded another class named Binder in your project. Try setting your CoreData entity's class name to something like BinderMO in XCode and re-create the class files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem was, but I deleted my Binder.h/.m files and recreated them and now it works. The only difference between the old ones and the new ones are that 'name' and 'lastOpened' switched places. Thanks for the help.

New Binder.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Cards;

@interface Binder : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * lastOpened;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *cards;
@end

@interface Binder (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addCardsObject:(Cards *)value;
- (void)removeCardsObject:(Cards *)value;
- (void)addCards:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeCards:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

New Binder.m:

```
#import "Binder.h"
#import "Cards.h"


@implementation Binder

@dynamic lastOpened;
@dynamic name;
@dynamic cards;

@end
```